# obtener valor de un campo en un tabla con JavaScrip

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

estoy intentando obtener el valor de un campo en especifico dentro de una tabla, los datos son traídos con AJAX de una API. He intentado con  `.value` pero creo que solo funciona para inputs.

Comment: Hola @Gabriela , creo que le falta mucha información a esta pregunta, normalmente esto lo puede cerrar , te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues código para poder trabajar con ello , y así podrán ayudarte como corresponde.Saludos!!!

Comment: Es necesario poner información, código, ejemplos, referencias o algo que permita a los demás ayudarte... ¿qué API? ¿En qué formato devuelve los datos? etc.

Answer (score 0):

he logrado solucionarlo, pido disculpas si fue algo poca la información pero lo vi lo suficientemente claro, a la fina he podido acceder al campo que deseaba de la siguiente forma;

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var dato1=x[2].innerHTML;
```

y asi solo cambiando el valor dentó de `[]` puedo acceder al campo especifico.

Saludos!

Comment: Descuida, Gabriela. Te doy la bienvenida y aprovecho para invitarte a [hacer el tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por el sitio. Cualquier duda nueva, no dudes en publicarla ;)